# Why does my code generate a new session or thread everytime it runs a query in loop?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mariadb

Why does the below code always generates a new thread as seen in mysql general query log?

I am doing performance improvements in my spring code,

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Item getItemBySKU(String domain, String sku) {
    return (Item) sesionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("From Item where domain=:domain and sku=:sku")
            .setParameter("domain", domain)
            .setParameter("sku", sku).uniqueResult();
}
```

It should reuse id

Comment: It's very unlikely that MySQL creates new thread for every request. It rather uses same threads from thread pool in cycle. Check thread ids, they must be repited.

Comment: What does `sesionFactory.getCurrentSession()` do?